# summernote multiple file upload

Tags: php, fileupload

Есть две textarea, summernote запускается следующим образом

```
      $('textarea').summernote({
    onImageUpload: function(files, editor, $editable) {
    sendFile(files[0],editor,$editable);
  },
      height: 300,                 // set editor height
      minHeight: null,             // set minimum height of editor
      maxHeight: null,             // set maximum height of editor
      focus: true,                 // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
    });
```

Загрузка файла

```
    function sendFile(file,editor,welEditable) {
   data = new FormData();
   data.append("file", file);
    $.ajax({
    url: "fileupload.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data) {
     $('textarea').summernote("insertImage", data, 'filename');
 },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
   }
 });
}
```

Проблема в том что если на странице несколько textarea, вставка файла происходит не всегда в нужную textarea.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Строку

   `sendFile(files[0],editor,$editable);`

   замените на:

   `sendFile(files[0],$(this),$editable);`
2. Строку:

   `$('textarea').summernote("insertImage", data, 'filename');`

   замените на:

   `editor.summernote("insertImage", data, 'filename');`

Comment: Все работает, спасибо огромное :)